# How to create elements inside a particular column and row of a grid, inside the C# file in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Inside the xaml file, I have created a Grid and a TextBox like so:

```
<Grid Margin="6">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox x:Name="tB" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap"
             BorderThickness="2" Margin="0, 0, 0, 16"
             Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
             Text="0" FontSize="36" TextAlignment="Right"
             />
</Grid>
```

Now for all the remaining columns and rows, I want to create an individual button inside them all. I don't think that repeating the same line code over and over, creating all the buttons individually would be a good idea.

I think using a for loop to create the buttons inside the C# script could work but I am not able to access the `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` properties inside the C# script

I hope you understand what I am trying to do, and if you can please help me with that I would really appreciate it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not able to access `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` because those properties don't exist on the `Grid` class.  What you're looking for is the `ColumnDefinitions` and `RowDefinitions` properties.

You first want to name your Grid so you can access it in your code-behind.

So:

```xml
<Grid Name="MySickGrid" Margin="6"> <!-- notice MySickGrid as the name! -->
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="tB" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap"
             BorderThickness="2" Margin="0, 0, 0, 16"
             Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
             Text="0" FontSize="36" TextAlignment="Right"
             />
    </Grid>
```

Then we can create a method to actually populate the grid like so:

```cs
public void AddButtons()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MySickGrid.RowDefinitions.Count; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < MySickGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; ++j)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Click += Click_EventHandler;
            button.Content = $"[{i}][{j}]";
            MySickGrid.Children.Add(button);
            Grid.SetRow(button, i);
            Grid.SetColumn(button, j);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, don't forget to actually call `AddButtons()`!

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AddButtons();
}
```

You may also notice that your TextBox is no longer showing.  This is because it's being covered by the buttons we're generating.  You'll need to modify which column and row you put the TextBox in if you wish to see it.

Comment: sorry but ive got another issue. now that the buttons are created i want to add an event to all the buttons, if you could help me out with that thanks

Comment: click event added :) @IEY

Answer (score 0):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Add buttons to each row and column in the Grid
    for (int row = 1; row < grid.RowDefinitions.Count; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; column++)
        {
            var button = new Button
            {
                Content = $"Button {row}-{column}",
                Margin = new Thickness(6),
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
                // You can customize other button properties here
            };

            // Set the row and column positions for the button
            Grid.SetRow(button, row);
            Grid.SetColumn(button, column);

            // Add the button to the Grid
            grid.Children.Add(button);
        }
    }
}
```

With this code, buttons will be dynamically created and added to the Grid for each row and column except the first row (where the TextBox is located). The buttons will have their row and column positions correctly set in the Grid. You can customize the button properties to fit your needs.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Add x:Name="grid" for access grid from your code.
Then you can populate it with your buttons.

```
for (int colIndex=0; colIndex<grid.Columns; colIndex++)
  for (int rowIndex=0; rowIndex<grid.Rows; rowIndex++)
{
  var btn = new Button();
  btn.Content = "Command";
  btn.MinWidth = 50;

  btn.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, columnIndex);
  btn.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, rowIndex);

  // add button to the grid
  grid.Childs.Add(btn);
}
```

Comment: This won't compile, because there is nothing like `grid.Columns`, `grid.Rows` and `grid.Childs`. There is also no good reason to use `DependencyObject.SetValue` directly. Use the Grid methods intended for setting the Row and Column properties.